# How to start service and redirect to another activity in a same time?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service

What I want is when I click on the button,start a service immediately.Once started the service,intent to another activity immediately.

Here is my code to achieve it:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
        //here I start the service
        Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, UploadService.class);
                intent.putExtra(UploadService.ID,id);
        startService(intent);

        //after start the service,I want to redirect to Activity2.class
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MyActivity.this,Activity2.class);
        startActivity(intent1);

        }
}
```

But when I do this,the service is not start,and not redirect to `Activity2.class`,instead it redirect to the previous activity.

I tried `intent` inside the `onHandleIntent(Intent intent)` of `Service.class` the problem still the same

**Here is what I tried in UploadService.class**:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
  //other code here

  Intent intent1 = new Intent(MyActivity.this,Activity2.class);
  startActivity(intent1);
}
```

But still the service not start,intent to the previous activity(the activity which MyActivity.class intent from).

So how can I redirect to another `activity` immediately just after start a `Service`?

**Edit:**
I already declare the `UploadService` in manifest like so:

```
<service
    android:name=".services.UploadService"
    android:enabled="true">
</service>
```

So what I still missing here??

Comment: Why you have used **MyActivity.this** context if you are calling this from Service ?

Comment: cause if just using `.this` it cannot resolve..If I doing wrong please tell me the correct way,willing to learn

Comment: @ken update your manifest decleration of service & make sure service class that extends service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have registered your Service class in manifest.xml.
Try changing your Service class name from 'Service' to some other name. As Service.java class is System class.

Try starting service like below

```
startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class));
```

**EDit**

More Clarification Firstly check your app is running or not. If your Application is not running then call this code.

```
Intent i = new Intent(context,SecondActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);   
context.startActivity(i);
```

If running then use this code

```
Intent i = new Intent(context,SecondActivity.class);    
context.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: I declare in manifest already,and Service is just write it here,actual is not Service.class

Comment: I need to putExtra to the intent,how can I putExtra if startService using ur solution?

Comment: startService(new Intent(context, MyService.class).putExtra(Service.ID,id)); Try this

Comment: But how to intent the to another another after start the service?You answer seems havent mention this

Comment: ya checked..I use your code in Edit section in `onStart` of the `service`,but it doesnt work,is still the same as stated in my question

Comment: Normally this is how all Start Service. I am not getting the issue. Make Sure the ServiceConnection class is declared in activity.

Comment: so normally after start the service,how to intent to another activity?so the service is run in background,and not blocking the UI right?